# Ruby - Write output to new terminal window

Tags: ruby, gnome-terminal

I was wondering whether it is possible to have a ruby script open a new terminal window and redirect its output to that newly-opened terminal window.

To open a new terminal, I currently do `system("gnome-terminal")`, however, after researching for a while, I still dont know how I could achieve the following ("pseudo code"):

```
variable = "test"
newTerminal = system("gnome-terminal")
puts variable to newTerminal
```

Is that even possible without going through major troubles?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Actually I am using Archlinux.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `exec gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'echo #{variable};exec $SHELL'"`  (you may need backticks surrounding everything from after the first exec to the end of the line)

Answer (score 1):

To do something similar on OSX (if ever someone runs into the same situation, yes I know this doesn't answer it for this specific situation) you can do:

```
variable = "test"
`osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"
  do script "echo #{variable}"
end tell'`
```

Note: This isn't exactly the same as using `puts` since it would actually execute the echo command multiple times if you wanted to print several things but its more of a foundation for how to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't easily test this for your system, but I'd try using [IO.popen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-c-popen) to open the terminal, which should allow you to write to the IO stream returned.